# Trigger Back to Top Function from within iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching a lot for the solution to this and can't figure it out. Tried a lot of methods I've seen but none seen to work.

Here is what I wanna do:

I have a main page with a navigation menu on its side, and all the content is loaded on iFrame. I wan't to know when the iFrame content was scrolled down to enable or disable Back to Top Button and also send the iFrame content back to top when clicking the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();   
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    }); 
    });
</script>
```

I've found this code but it is made to work on the current page you're on. I've tried a lot with document.parent, parent, trigger(), but nothing seen to work. I could paste this code on all pages that will load on the iFrame but what I want is to place the back to top button on a static button menu that I have on the top of the content so it can be seen from wherever part of the text you are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting this script in the iframe head? btw its parent.document not document.parent.

Comment: How can I do this? I'm inserting iframe inside a div like this: <iframe id="content-nav" name="content-nav" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   button = document.getElementById('topButton'); 
   button.style.display = "block";
 }
});

function toTop(){
document.getElementById('iframeContainer').scrollTop = 0;
}
```

and just hide the button. once the bottom is reached it should change the style to block and make it visible. Call the toTop() function with your newly visible button.